# How to find xpath or css locator of error message label Selenium WebDriver

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, automation, webdriver

### Test case:

1.Go to [sample test URL ] : http://www.foxsports.com/mlb/just-a-bit-outside/story/mlb-teams-that-dont-trade-with-each-other-030415
2. Scroll the page to bottom and Observe the facebook comment module.
3.Without facebook signIn ,Click on'Comment using ' button and Click on 'facebook' dropdown option from dropdownList.

**To test: Error message label 'Please fill out this field is displayed or not and Comment box border color changes.**

I'm unable to **find the xpath/css of 'Please fill out this field' error label** and color of comment box.

Is this scenerio possible to test though selenium webdriver automation?
Could anyone please help me on this...
Note: This is exact facebook api being implemented in project website.

### Questions:

1.How to find the xpath/css of this element?
2.Is this scenerio possible to test via selenium automation testing.
3.In what ways we can test this.

I use Selenium webDriver 2.0 ,Java for the same.
I tried through selenium IDE to capture the locat!

Comment: Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to find xpath using ff is to use fitepath and firebug add-ons installed in it.
Using this all you need to do is just point it with add-on opened in your browser.. You will xpath.
Pretty straight forward.. Saves your time.. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying.I meant I also tried with Selenium Ide and also with firebug./irepath,Default developers tools of all browsers. Sorry for the confusion.Could you please try with above mentioned steps and provide your thoughts on it.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The field that you are seeing in this case is utilizing browser level HTML5 validation. See [here for more information and some examples](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/). Because the validation elements are not attached to the DOM, you will not be able to test this using automation (at least as far as I know).

The only thing you could test for is the presence of the HTML5 validation attributes such as `required`, `number` etc. If you try duplicating the manual test case in different browsers that support HTML5 you should be able to see unique styling for each. Essentially it is up to the browser to implement the validation logic.

Comment: This is a helpful comment. I'd also add here that since the comment plugin you're testing is provided by Facebook (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) there's an argument to be made that by testing it in depth you're likely duplicating effort already made by Facebook's test team. So you might want to simply verify that it appears and is usable, rather than focus on its corner cases and cosmetic details.

Comment: Thanks shri046 and @Bill Agee
Could you again help on this:
1.Now what to reply my client or My manager about this.I mean plz help me to write logical reason/explanation
2.I guess I m not able to get d comments i.e presence of the .... number etc.''.Also,'unique styling for each' .Could you please post a SS for this.
4. comment 'So ---------cases and cosmetic details. – 
 Did you mean that I should only just check the functionality of this module i.e user is able to post the comments or not? and that module is displayed and other functionality id possible.